# A New Blog Post is showing on top of my home page from Unknown user cyberanon - How to Remove the post?

Tags: php, mysql

I have just launched our brand new blog website (php/mysql). I don't have any idea about cyber security. Yesterday we published a topic on coronavirus vaccine. I just noticed a new post is sitting on the home page Title: "Mr.Krungzx" and user "cyberanon". I tried to search in the admin panel, but didn't find anything related to this unknown post. We are using SSL to make our website secure. But seems like nothing worked, and I am clueless what to do next or what are the possible resolution and how to clean up this post from our web page also make sure this don't happen again. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately (and I really mean this as gently as possible), it sounds like you are in over your head.  It sounds like you setup some blogging software but don't really know anything about how these things work.  To be clear - that's perfectly normal.  No one is good at everything - we're all learning new things each day.  In this particular case though, if you really don't understand anything about the technologies you are doing, your odds of doing this "right" are very small.

Comment: There are clearly some glaring security issues somewhere, so even if you managed to scrub this post off of your website it's quite possible that someone would hack their way  back in quickly anyway.  Your best bet may be to accept the fact that managing your blog software may be a task best left in someone else's hands for now.  There are many services available that will host your blog for you (both paid and free).  You may save yourself a lot of trouble to stick with something like that for now.

Comment: How to remove it? That's a question that depends on the type of blogging app you are using. How to prevent it from happening again? Without knowing how it happened, we can only guess. Reset all passwords to something strong.

Comment: Thank You for Your quick response. Will reset all the password for sure. It's true that I am not very tech savvy, but always love to learn new things specially if it related to cyber security :-)

Comment: @Arnav Unfortunately "how do I secure my application" is a very broad question and not a good fit for how this site operates.  You said that it is a custom built application.  That means that the issue could be just about anywhere.  If this is the first time you've built a web application then the main concepts you need to familiarize yourself with are [defense in depth](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/defence-in-depth-and-how-it-applies-to-web-applications/) and the [OWasp top ten](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/)

Comment: Note that asking how to properly secure a web application is pretty much the same as asking, "How do I build a web application?" in terms of its breadth.  There are a large variety of topics, techniques, and technologies that you will have to learn at all layers of the system.  If you built your web application without understanding basics of web application security, then it will help to understand that in order to this "right" you may have to throw away most of what you have already done.

Comment: @ConorMancone Will surely study the links you shared.  I understand this is a platform for experience people. I got a lot of experience in IT (Unfortunately Not In Development & security). Will come back with more mature queries. Thanks

Comment: Please don't take my comments as an attempt to be dismissive!  As I said, we all have to start somewhere.  I can't even tell you how many security issues there were in my first web applications.  All I'm trying to say is that learning how to secure web applications well is as much of a learning process as learning how to build web applications in the first place.

Comment: You're welcome to post questions here even as someone who is brand new to things - after all, how else would you learn?  This site isn't designed for only experienced security people.  Your only issue at the moment is that stackexchange in general prefers clear, concise questions rather than broad ones like "How do I secure my web application?".  Those sorts of questions are a better fit for discussion boards, and this just isn't a discussion board.

Answer (score 1):

This can be all sorts of things.
As your blog uses a MySQL database, check if the unwanted post is in there. If it is, and no-one authorized placed it there, you might have a breach somewhere.

Make sure that the database (phpMyAdmin?) and controlpanel of the blog are not using default or easy login credentials (e.g 'root' without password). Also check that visitors can not create new blog posts.

If the post is on the homepage but not in the database, try checking the source files which generate this page. There might be something in there.

Furthermore, using SSL is not making a website secure. It secures (encrypts) the connection between a visitor (client) and the webserver. It does not secure the application itself against malicious actors.

For more help please give us some more information, is the blog running on a known platform (e.g WordPress) or custom build? Can guests place new content or comments?

Comment: Thank You for providing the possible reasons.It really helps a beginner like me to learn new things. I was able to delete the post from admin, but yes it was there in the database. No I am not using root and password is not that simple. The platform is custom build (php/myadmin). Guests can comment using facebook comment plugin but  only admin can post content. What all I should do to make the site secure? Just wonder how can someone inserted value into database? Only changing password is OK? Or need to work more and How? Thanks Again for Your Response.

Comment: Changing passwords is the first step. Also the links Conor provided can be usefull. If you have some experience in IT, you can dive into the webserver/mysql log files to see what happened. Perhaps there is something there (if you remember the time on which the post was placed, this narrows your search). As the blog is custom build, make sure the 'create new post' page is secure and not accessible by non-authorized users.